# Checking if JoinDate is within x amount of days

Tags: discord, momentjs

Using moment, I'm trying to create an if statement to see if their joinDate is within 14 days.

```
let joinDate = ${moment(member.joinedAt).format("YYYY, MMMM Do dddd, HH:mm:ss")}
```

That's my current code to format when the user joined.
Basically what I'm saying (if you're not following) is how would I check if `joinDate` is within the last 14 days?

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna use momentjs [`diff`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)  function to get the days difference between the current date and the input .
A Snippet for your reference

```js
const selectedDate = "2021-08-07";
const date_temp = moment().diff(selectedDate, "days", true);
console.log('Is within 14 days? ',date_temp >= 0 && date_temp <= 14);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```